# Calculate the sum of each column of an HTML table in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a table where each row is printed using the `ngFor` attribute. I want to calculate the sum of each column.

In jQuery we can calculate the sum of a group of HTML elements with the same class. Is there any way to do that in Typescript?

Or is there any other way to do that?

```
export class Sum implements OnInit {
  basePay: number;
  bonusPercent: number;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.basePay = 10000;
    this.bonusPercent = 0.12;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Base</td>
    <td *ngFor="let year of [0,1,2,3,4]">{{ basePay }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Variable incentive</td>
    <td *ngFor="let year of [0,1,2,3,4]">{{ basePay * bonusPercent }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Total Target Cash (TTC) (Local)</td>
    <td *ngFor="let year of [0,1,2,3,4]">{{ basePay + (basePay * bonusPercent )}}</td>
  </tr>
 <tr><td>Sum</td><td>row 1 + row 2+ row 3</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to do that in typescript?

Yes but *not* in the `*ngFor` directly. Create your final object graph in the `ngOnInit` function and then display the values using the template and `*ngFor`.

Here is an example but keep in mind you did not illustrate what you expect the totals to be or where they come from. You did not actually do anything with the year value or index.

As a side note you can use an html [column span](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp) instead of creating empty or repetitive columns. This is in reference to the first row.

```
export class Sum implements OnInit {
  basePay: number;
  bonusPercent: number;
  data: {incentives: number[], ttc: number[], totals?: number[]};

  ngOnInit() {
    this.basePay = 10000;
    this.bonusPercent = 0.12;
    const years = [0,1,2,3,4];

    data = {
      incentives: years.map(_=> basePay * bonusPercent),
      ttc: years.map(_ => basePay + (basePay * bonusPercent)),
    };
    data.totals = years.map((_,i) => data.incentives[i] + data.ttc[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Base</td>
    <td colspan="5"> {{basePay}} </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Variable incentive</td>
    <td *ngFor="let incentive of data.incentives">{{ incentive }} 
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Total Target Cash (TTC) (Local) </td>
    <td *ngFor="let ttc of data.ttc">{{ ttc }} 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sum</td>
    <td *ngFor="let total of data.totals">{{ total }} 
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry you misunderstood the question. I am trying to calculate sum of html table column. Question has been updated hope it makes sense now

Comment: @NareshShetty - the answer stays the same. You do the calculation *in the component* and not in the HTML template. One of the reasons is that the *ngFor can be reexecuted on every change detection which could result in either side effects or extra overhead.